# How do I keep browser from listing suggestions for input-field (not necessarily the same as disabling autocomplete/autofill)?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

I currently have autocomplete='off' on the "form" tag.
I currently have autocomplete='random-stuff' on the "input" tag.
Per many different suggestions I found on Stack Overflow for disabling auto-fill, I have tried various values for the autocomplete attribute: "off", "false", "disabled", "disable", "new-password", "[random]".  Chrome's auto-fill seems to be disabled (somewhat) but the auto-fill light-yellow background still appears if one selects one of the suggestions. But nothing I've tried keeps Chrome from offering suggestions.

I want to disable auto-fill **AND** prevent suggestions for the input-field.  I'm looking for a solution using any combination of PHP, HTML, CSS, or Javascript.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for google chrome 69.0.3497.81 autocomplete='off' work fine

Comment: I'm currently using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Thanks.  I just upgraded Chrome from ver 68.something to 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit).  I have the form tag attribute autocomplete='off', and the input tag attribute autocomplete='off' and Chrome still gives me input hints - but they're different now.  The input hints used to end with a link to manage Autofill.  Now it shows some hints and ends with a link to "Manage address...".  In fact, all my input fields in the form have the same hints.  Chrome seems to think that they are about "addresses" and the hints are all from the address field.

Comment: @JohnMullaney for disable Chrome address suggestion use <input type="search">

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no change.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with a website I maintain after upgrading to 69.0.3497.92. Still searching for an answer. Any updates on this?